# How to remove geometric data from PostGIS tables

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1, shapefile

I have 2 tables generated from shapefiles. One table has Land areas and another has water regions. How can I subtract the water regions of second table in first table.

Something like this

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET table1.geom AS table1.geom-table2.geom
```

It can be done easily using QGIS GEO Processing Difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you can join the tables**, use Tommaso Di Bucchianico's answer. It's the most efficient query.

**If you can't join the tables** (it's a common case with GIS tables), use **ST_Intersects** with **ST_Difference** :

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.geom = ST_Difference(table1.geom, table2.geom)
FROM table2
WHERE ST_Intersects(table1.geom, table2.geom);
```

If `table1.geom` type is MultiPolygon, use ST_Multi :

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.geom = ST_Multi(ST_Difference(table1.geom, table2.geom))
FROM table2
WHERE ST_Intersects(table1.geom, table2.geom);
```

Comment: Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon) i am getting this error

Comment: `table1.geom` column type is MultiPolygon and `ST_Difference(table1.geom, table2.geom)` returns a Polygon. That's why you get this error. You have to use ST_Multi().

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [ST_Difference()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html). I think, you need also a column as foreign key for joining the two tables, in example a id column:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.geom = ST_Difference(table1.geom, table2.geom) 
FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```